# CMB2 slow at loading images

Tags: php, wordpress, cmb2

I'm trying to setup some custom fields using CMB2 for WordPress. So far simple text fields works, and so does images, but it takes +2min to load an single image using the multiple file field.

This is how I use it:

**Functions.php**

```
function cmb2_metaboxes() {

$prefix = '_npport_';

$cmb->add_field( array(
    'name' => 'Test File List',
    'desc' => '',
    'id'   => 'wiki_test_file_list',
    'type' => 'file_list',
    // 'preview_size' => array( 100, 100 ), // Default: array( 50, 50 )
    // 'query_args' => array( 'type' => 'image' ), // Only images attachment
    // Optional, override default text strings
    'text' => array(
        'add_upload_files_text' => 'Replacement', // default: "Add or Upload Files"
        'remove_image_text' => 'Replacement', // default: "Remove Image"
        'file_text' => 'Replacement', // default: "File:"
        'file_download_text' => 'Replacement', // default: "Download"
        'remove_text' => 'Replacement', // default: "Remove"
    ),
) );
}
```

**Display content on single view**

```
function cmb2_output_file_list( $file_list_meta_key, $img_size = 'medium' ) {

                // Get the list of files
                $files = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $file_list_meta_key, 1 );

                echo '<div class="file-list-wrap">';
                // Loop through them and output an image
                foreach ( (array) $files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url ) {
                    echo '<div class="file-list-image">';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $img_size );
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            };
            cmb2_output_file_list( 'wiki_test_file_list', 'small' );
```

I guess something with the code must be wrong, but I can't really figure out what. Link for demo: [link](http://nrport.weshape.dk/portfolio/example-port/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, and with no problem at all.

Check `$files` variable, how many items are there, i think, that you inserted too many items into `'add_upload_files_text'` accidentaly.